# Ibatis insert operation

Tags: java, database, ibatis

Hi I am trying to insert a list of object through ibatis but i am getting an exception like
org.apache.ibatis.mapping.SqlMapperException: The expression 'boxlist' evaluated to a null value.

```
<insert id="insertList" parameterType="java.util.List">
    INSERT INTO boxtable (
    size,length)
    VALUES
    <foreach item="box" collection="boxList" separator=",">
        (#{box.size},#{box.length})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

My dao class is like

```
public void insert(List<box> boxList)
        throws SQLException {

    try {                            
        sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(AUTO_COMMIT); 
        int status = sqlSession.insert("insertlist", boxList);
        logger.debug("status :: " + status);
        sqlSession.commit();
    } catch (Throwable ee) {
        logger.error("e", ee);
    sqlSession.rollback();
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me out???

Comment: The error message is pretty clear I think. The value you're sending into the expression evaluates to `null`

Comment: No list is not empty..I am calling this function from other function and passing the list

Answer (score 1):

If I remember it right you need to pass an object containing `boxList` property or you could pass a map containing the `boxList` key. For example

```
public class Wrapper {
    private List<box> boxList;
}


<insert id="insertList" parameterType="Wrapper">
    INSERT INTO boxtable (
    size,length)
    VALUES
    <foreach item="box" collection="boxList" separator=",">
        (#{box.size},#{box.length})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Comment: I have to pass a list which contains objects

Comment: create a class like Wrapper and set the box List in that object and pass that object.

Answer (score 0):

try using `<isPropertyAvailable>` before the `<foreach>`  in your sql statement. Also you could try using the `<iterate>` but don't forget to append [] to ur boxlist (as in `#boxlist[]#`)

For more on dynamic sql statements in ibatis follow this [link](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html)